# Which is the more efficient syntax for NAND (not both true) in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, syntax, coding-style, standards

The [NAND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic#NAND) logic gate for two conditions (A and B) is `true` as long as either condition is true, or none of the conditions is true; and it is `false` if **both** conditions are true.

```
F NAND F = T
F NAND T = T
T NAND F = T
T NAND T = F
```

In C# I can write this in at least two ways:

```
!(A && B)
```

or

```
(!A || !B)
```

Which is **more efficient**?

It seems to me that `if(A)` then B is always tested and `if(!A)` then B is never tested.

But then the first condition must invert the result....

Comment: inverting the result is the same as swapping the code in the `else` with the code in the `if`... no actual runtime instruction needed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not quite as simple.  The C# language doesn't model a NAND gate at all with the && operator.  That operator has *short-circuiting* behavior, *very* convenient in a C# program.  And common behavior for the curly-brace languages, an expression like this doesn't crash your code:

```
arr[] = somefunction();
int ix = foo;
if (ix < arr.Length && arr[ix] == 42) {
    EmailBookRecommendation();
}
```

But that's a very inefficient version of the expression, this one is *way* more performant:

```
if (ix < arr.Length & arr [ix] == 42)
```

Which is a perfectly legal expression, the & operator works just fine with boolean operands.  But unfortunately this one crashes your code.  It evaluates the array indexing expression and that goes Kaboom! with IndexOutOfRangeException.

That's not ever a problem with a NAND gate, it doesn't crash when the first input is F :)  There are **many** possible C# expressions where that's not a problem.  You really should favor the & operator for those.  It makes a *huge* difference.  So always write something like this:

```
if (ix >= 1 & ix <= 42)
```

Which of course can never fail.  To understand why the && operator is so much more inefficient than the & operator, you have to understand *branch prediction*.  That's covered very well in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/17034).

Comment: In my particular case, I am comparing integer values to literals. So it's something like `if(Foo.A==CONST1 NAND Foo.B==CONST2){Bar();}` So I could easily use the "&" rather than "&&" without procedural complication or slowdown. If I read you correctly it is more performant to use "&" and "predict" the resulting condition? I'm not quite sure I follow.

Comment: Except that (1) the question didn't ask about `&`, and (2) `&&` is not "much more inefficient than the `&` operator", it depends completely on the expressions involved.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "huge difference"?

Comment: I think the second answer in the question you linked to actually explains why && is good to use, or rather that sorting data intelligently pays dividends. But it depends on context. It certainly augments the first answer, and both (and the question) were informative.

Why wouldn't you just write `(A !& B)` though? Assuming you're working with two boolean variables and not testing expressions that could have negative consequences.

Answer (score 4):

Neither.  They both have exactly the same short circuiting behavior, and the compiler will turn both into MSIL requesting a test of `A`, followed by a conditional branch.  The branch where `A` was true will then have a test of `B`.

What you should be worrying about is:

```
!(A && B)
```

vs

```
!(B && A)
```

which are different in case either `A` or `B` causes side effects or complicated calculations.

The possible exception to both being the same is if you have a custom definition of `operator!`, in which case they aren't actually equivalent at all.

Comment: assuming A and B are both `bool` then there is no functional difference?

Comment: @Matthew: Assuming both `A` and `B` are local variables of type `bool`, there should not be any difference in the generated code.

Comment: I was thinking it would depend on the likelihood of A being `true` but you're telling me they compile to identical code? Interesting.

Comment: @Matthew: The definition of `&&` and `||` both *require* the compiler to skip testing `B` if `A` is found to be false.

Comment: I don't think so... `A || B` will test B if A is `false` .. It will not test B is A is `true`.

Comment: @Matthew: In your question I see `(!A) || (!B)`, not `A || B`.  So it will test `B` if `(!A)` is false, which means only if `A` is true.

Comment: I have edited my question, trying to explain why your assertion that they compile to the same code is confusing. I accept that they have the same short-circuit... but then doesn't the first need an additional operation to invert the result?

Comment: @Matthew: There are two blocks of code, a *then-part* and an *else-part*.  For both, the compiler will jump straight to the *then-part* if `A` is true, otherwise test `B`, and jump to the *then-part* if `B` is true (if not, jump to *else-part*).  There's no operation to invert an if-statement, it just switches the jump to either the *then-part* or the *else-part*.  If you wrote `C = !(A || B);`, it might be different, but probably not.

Comment: @Matthew: If you do find any differences in the generated MSIL, please post them and we'll take a closer look.

Comment: This answer *completely* misses the point, the OP asked about *efficiency*.

Comment: @Hans: If you can't understand that two pieces of source code which compile to the same thing therefore have the same efficiency...

Answer (score -1):

My short test of 10000 comparisons between the two says that the firsoneis faster.

it says the first needed totally of 1353 ticks and the second total of 1373 ticks.

EDIT: then again i tried this a few fore times and the results variate so they are both the same.